# Laravel , rich text display error

Tags: laravel, richtextbox

I saved a rich text in the database , and  once i display it , it gives me this :

```
"<p>test&nbsp;<strong>fwefwfw4fwf4wfw4f4wf</strong></p>".
```

if you can help me i'd be thankful .

Comment: How do you display it? Show us what you've done and how you tried solving it

Comment: Are you using blade syntax to display it? Can you show us a snippet of what your view looks like?

Answer (score 1):

How you render your code in blade?

```
{!! $post->body !!}
```